# in node.js, how does one file in a module see functions in another file in the module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

in a module containing two files in `./modx`: `modx.js` and `helper.js`:

./modx/package.json:

```
{ "name" : "module x",
  "main" : "./modx.js" }
```

./modx/helper.js:

```
function subFunc() { }
```

./modx/modx.js:

```
exports.mainFunc = function() {
   var x = subFunc();
}
```

how do I make `subFunc()` in `helper.js` visible to `modx.js` when both are in the `modx` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only object in script `A` visible from script `B` is `module.exports`. Adding objects/functions to `module.exports` (just like you did it with `mainFunc`) makes them visible from the outside. There is no other way.

Comment: tried that.  even tried `require("./modx")` in `modx.js`, but no luck with either `subFunc()` or `modx.subFunc()` - does something else need to be in the `package.json` to reference the `helper.js` file?

Comment: @ccyoung I'm not sure what you are trying to do. `package.json` is a file which **only** npm uses. It has no meaning in Node.JS.

Comment: That's not quite true: `require` now makes (very limited) use of `package.json` (see the "Folders as Modules" section of the docs for modules).

Comment: @ebohlman I've read docs and I stand corrected. Didn't know that. In that case I'm not sure why this is not working for OP though.

Answer (score 3):

Inside ./modx/helper.js

```
var subFunc = function subFunc() {}
exports.subFunc = subFunc;
```

Inside .modx/modx.js

```
var helper = require('./helper.js');
exports.mainFunc() {
    var x = helper.subFunc();
}
```

The result here is that the subFunc function in helper.js is externally available and the mainFunc in modx.js is externally available.

Comment: if you want to do that, then `helper` need to become a `module` along with its own directory, package.json, etc.  here it's the case where there is more than one file in a module - if possible.